How to automatically import Keyvault references in my Logic app env variables after a Terraform deploy
I am deploying an environment for my Logic Apps (standard if that matters) using Terraform, this includes the necessary secrets that I put in the keyvault to add as references in the environment variables.
There is just one problem, after the Terraform script, I have to manually click on the button
"Pull reference values"

Thats not good, and so far I can't find a way in terraform to do that. After some research I found that I can probably do a manual http call to the API with "data" or a null_resource with provisioners, but apparently those are to be used as a last resort.
Any idea?
Thanks
----- UPDATE -----
resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "logic_app" {
  name                       = "la-${var.project}-${var.region}-${var.environment}"
  resource_group_name        = module.mod-resource-group.name
  location                   = var.location
  storage_account_name       = module.mod-storage-account.name
  storage_account_access_key = module.mod-storage-account.primary_access_key
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_service_plan.service_plan.id
  version                    = "~4"
  https_only                 = true

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  app_settings = {
    APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = try(module.mod-application-insights.connection_string, null)
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY        = try(module.mod-application-insights.instrumentation_key, null)
    apim-oauth-username                   = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${module.mod-azurerm-key-vault-secrets.keyvault_secrets_update.apim-oauth-username})"
...
}

----- UPDATE 2 -----
  module "mod-azurerm-key-vault-access-policy" {
     source                                                    = "git@xxx/Terraform/mod-azurerm-key-vault-access-policy?ref=tags/2.1.0"
    keyvault-id                                               = module.mod-azurerm-key-vault.id
    tenant-id                                                 = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    access_policies = [
      {
        object-id               = azurerm_logic_app_standard.logic_app.identity[0].principal_id
        key_permissions         = []
        secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List"]
        certificate_permissions = []
        storage_permissions     = []
      },
      {
        object-id               = var.apim-principal-id
        key_permissions         = []
        secret_permissions      = ["Get", "List"]
        certificate_permissions = []
        storage_permissions     = []
      }
    ]
  }


Can you please show us the relevant Terraform code?

Not sure what that would be but added a sample of the logic app and the part where i call the ref from keyvault. What do you need? Again, insertion into keyvault works fine and the ref is created, it's just that I need to hit manually the "pull references" button and I don't know how

Manually hitting the "pull references" button means you will be executing an operation using your own permissions, which is not the same as using the System Assigned identity of the Logic App.

I'm wondering if your logic app identity has permissions to access the keyvault. If I were you I'd add a keyvault access policy with permissions to get the secrets.

ih, right, it's there, but its from a module used by my employer which I can't really show, I can show the call to it though
